# How can I access these nested attributes in parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the value of one of the parameters sent, but I'm using nested attributes and when creating an object, the nested attributes have a kind of token, which prevents me from accessing the attributes through the key.

How can I access these nested attributes in parameters?

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xodtke+W96O+hiEH8AvnK4F5XZF5U9b8148YyVTsZX5XNlkdOxmv4RTge+9MmOtfoNLOaUZbcpMcTVxRFSwRUQ==", "comanda"=>{"cliente_id"=>"1", "forma_pagamento_id"=>"1", "R$valor_total"=>"", "status"=>"false", "itens_comandas_attributes"=>{"1664413214142"=>{"produto_id"=>"1", "valor"=>"", "quantidade"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1664413217936"=>{"produto_id"=>"2", "valor"=>"", "quantidade"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Comanda"}
```

Here, in the nested attributes, this token "1664413214142" that contains the values, but if I try to access the "product_id" key, it doesn't return anything:

```
    puts params[:comanda].has_key?(:itens_comandas_attributes)
```

> true

```
    puts params[:comanda][:itens_comandas_attributes]
```

> it doesn't return anything

Comment: what if you try ```params.require(:comanda).permit(:itens_comandas_attributes)```

Comment: What does `puts params["comanda"]["itens_comandas_attributes"]` return?

Comment: @Haumer There is a method "comanda_params" that I already allow the parameters:



`def comanda_params`
`params.require(:comanda).permit(:itens_comanda, :cliente_id, :forma_pagamento_id, :valor_total, :status, itens_comandas_attributes: [:id, :comanda, :produto_id,  :quantidade, :valor, :_destroy])`

Comment: but in your example you arent using it.

Comment: @FabianWinkler 
It returned a hash, with the data referring to items_comandas_atribbutes `{"1664826187696"=>{"produto_id"=>"1", "valor"=>"", "quantidade"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}` , but I still can't access the data contained in this hash because it has an id that changes in all submissions  `"1664826187696"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the nested attributes using the following syntax:

```
params[:comanda][:itens_comandas_attributes]["1664413214142"][:produto_id]
```

You can also access the nested attributes using the following syntax:

```
params[:comanda][:itens_comandas_attributes].values[0][:produto_id]
# params[:comanda][:itens_comandas_attributes].values[0]["produto_id"]
```